# Not awaitable method exception thowing inconsistent behaviour

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

So I read on async/await and somewhere, someplace I read that if you don't await an async method you basically lose it. It fires and forgets and goes into the AEeher and if it throws an exception - you will never know.

This was the example the author used:

```
    static async void OnButtonClick()
    {
        yolo();
        string imageUrl = null;
        try
        {
            DownloadAndBlur(imageUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    static async Task DownloadAndBlur(string url)
    {
        if (url == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));
        }
    }
```

Indeed, if I call the `OnButtonClick()` method from my code no exception gets thrown, or rather, nothing about an exception is printed on the console. While if I await the `DownloadAndBlur` method - an exception is written to the console.

So I tried to replicate the behaviour and wrote this:

```
    static async void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
        yolo();
        Console.WriteLine(2);
    }

    static Task yolo()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

But an exception is thrown and my debugging session catches it. So what is different, because I think they are the same.

Comment: `static Task yolo()` isn't asynchronous method, this is a method which returns value of type `Task`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Execute` method is not fire-and-forget. It is [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

```
static async void Execute()
{
    YoloAsync();
}
```

Exceptions in `async void` methods are thrown in the current `SynchronizationContext` (or in the `ThreadPool` if the [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) is null), which normally results to the crashing of the process ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs.html#353e7ecf1a8c2f91)).

Next, the `YoloAsync` method is not marked with the [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) modifier.

```
static Task YoloAsync()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

[Semantically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) it is an asynchronous method since it returns a `Task`, but the task is not generated from an async-state-machine. So the code inside the `YoloAsync` method is executed synchronously like any other method, and unlike the async-state-machine-generated methods that propagate their exceptions through the `Task` they return.

Comment: aw, dammit, I was falsely led to belive `async` does nothing more than allow you to use the `await` keyword in the method. Thanks!

Comment: @user13288253 yeap, this is also what I thought. Apparently there are always some unexpected intricacies lurking around to make our lives <del>difficult</del> interesting. :-) If you want take a look at [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) related blog post by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: What do you mean by "the default SynchronizationContext if the Current is null"?

Comment: @PauloMorgado it is an error. I was under the impression that the exception is thrown on a cached instance of the base [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) class, but it is actually thrown directly on the `ThreadPool`. I edited my answer to correct this error.

Answer (score -2):

Maxim 26. "Fire and Forget" is fine, provided you never actually forget.

Getting a Exception in Multitasking is always difficulty.

If you are doing Mutlthreading, it is actually trivially easy to loose all exceptions by default. The thread itself swallows all Exceptions. This is the worst case that has to be handeled.

As a result, Multitasking approaches always catch all exceptions, then expose them in the Result. [Task has a property for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception). So Does [RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs).

One job of the continuation code, is to check for and re-raise any Exceptions. It is something Task has to do for Multithreading support, even if it does not nessearily make sense with mere Multitasking.