# MVC async function not catching exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I've not got much experience with async programming in MVC, and I'm not sure what's going on.
I have an MVC controller with a function:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SectionMassUpdate(SectionMassUpdateViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var status = _sectionService.Update(model.SectionID, model.CompID, model.DateCompleted);

                if (!status.IsValid)
                {
                    ModelState.AddValidationErrors(status);

                }
                else { return Json(new { success = true }); }

            }

            return PartialView("_sectionUpdate", model);
        }
```

IN this post fuction, as you can see it calls a function in another class.  The function being called

```
public ServiceStatus Update(int sectionID, int compID, DateTIme dateCompleted)
{
     throw new Exception();
}
```

As is, when I post to the SectionMassUpdate function in the controller, nothing happens.  It goes to the call, and no exception is thrown or anything.  If I make the SectionMassUpdate function synchronous and remove the async and Task, then an exception is thrown.   Why is this and what do I do to make the exception thrown instead of the page doing nothing.

Comment: Do you actually await the Function? If you do not, it is very common for Exceptions to be swallowed by Multitasking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689900/not-awaitable-method-exception-thowing-inconsistent-behaviour

Comment: That can't happen! Are you sure `ModelState.IsValid` is `true`? It can't be.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer will be to make your service method Update async and use await in the calling statement in controller.

Comment: ModelState.IsValid is true Paulo Morgado.  When I step through, it gets to the Update call and then just stops debugging.  Nothin happens, and hte application is running.  I can click the submit button on the page and the debugging starts stepping through again.  I have trued changing both methods (controller method and the service Update method) to async, and the exception is still not thrown.